Universal semistable curve
For the moduli of stable curve, we have the result by Deligne-Mumford-Knudsen that there's an isomorphism of moduli spaces
$$\Phi : \overline{\mathcal{X}}_{g,n} \xrightarrow{\sim} \overline{\mathcal{M}}_{g,n+1}$$
over $\overline{\mathcal{M}}_{g,n}$, where $\overline{\mathcal{X}}_{g,n}$ is the universal curve over $\overline{\mathcal{M}}_{g,n}$ and the map is given by stable reduction.
My question is what happens in the semistable case: As was mentioned in this MO post, the moduli of semistable curves is algebaic. I believe semistable reduction gives a map
$$\Phi^{\operatorname{ss}} : \overline{\mathcal{X}}^{\operatorname{ss}}_{g,n} \to \overline{\mathcal{M}}^{\operatorname{ss}}_{g,n+1}$$
Take $g>0,n=0$. A point $(X,x)$  of $\overline{\mathcal{X}}^{\operatorname{ss}}_{g,0}$ will fail to be in $\overline{\mathcal{M}}^{\operatorname{ss}}_{g,1}$ only if $x$ is not smooth, in which case the semistable reduction will be the curve $X$ with a rational bridge added at $x$ and with the point $1$ marked. On the other hand for a smooth point $y \in X$, the $1$-pointed semistable curve $(X \vee_{y \sim 0} \mathbb{P}^1,\infty)$ is not of this form. So it seems $\Phi^{\operatorname{ss}}$ is not surjective. Is it an embedding?

The usual notation for the stack that you denote $\overline{\mathcal{M}}^{\text{ss}}{g,n}$ is $\mathfrak{M}{g,n}$.  Yes, there is an $1$-morphism from the universal curve over $\mathfrak{M}{g,n}$ to $\mathfrak{M}{g,n+1}$ in the way that you describe.  You do also need to address what happens when $x$ "crosses" one of the $n$ marked points $y_\ell$.  In that case, you "sprout" a rational tail that is attached to the original curve at $y_\ell$ and contains $x$ as well as the $\ell^{\text{th}}$ marked point (and no other marked points).  The $1$-morphism is representable by open immersions.

Thank you! Do you know a reference for the last statement (open immersion) by any chance?

Oops, I was wrong.  The image of the $1$-morphism is open.  However, the original $1$-morphism is not immersive.  Consider first one of the three stable $4$-pointed curves in the boundary of $\overline{\mathcal{M}}_{0,4}$.  Then consider the associated semistable curve that has one (unstable) rational bridge between the two components of the stable curve.  When we add a fifth marked point on the rational bridge, how do we know which of the two semistable curves it comes from?  In fact, it comes from both.
